# display full calendar on view laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

hello i used fullcalendar and html collective to display a full calendar on laravel 5.4 it worked when i return the response()->json($data) but when i tried to display my calender on the my welcome view i had empty page :/ .

```js
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
   },
   defaultDate: '2017-05-12',
   navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
   editable: true,
   eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
   events: [
    {
     title: 'All Day Event',
     start: '2017-05-01'
    },
    {
     title: 'Long Event',
     start: '2017-05-07',
     end: '2017-05-10'
    },
    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
     id: 999,
     title: 'Repeating Event',
     start: '2017-05-16T16:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Conference',
     start: '2017-05-11',
     end: '2017-05-13'
    },
    {
     title: 'Meeting',
     start: '2017-05-12T10:30:00',
     end: '2017-05-12T12:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Lunch',
     start: '2017-05-12T12:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Meeting',
     start: '2017-05-12T14:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Happy Hour',
     start: '2017-05-12T17:30:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Dinner',
     start: '2017-05-12T20:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Birthday Party',
     start: '2017-05-13T07:00:00'
    },
    {
     title: 'Click for Google',
     url: 'http://google.com/',
     start: '2017-05-28'
    }
   ]
  });
  
 });

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
{!! Html::style('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.min.css') !!}
<style>

 body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
 }

 #calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

{!! Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') !!}
    {!! 
     {!! Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') !!}Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') !!}
```

Comment: did you check your console for errors? Pretty sure you need to load jquery and moment _before_ the fullCalendar library. I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using to load the JS files, but it does look like you're loading them after the fullCalendar library. Also consider moving the includes to the `<head>` section of the page. There's no particular reason for them to be down the bottom like that. It's not clear when they are loaded in relation to your `<script>` block that contains the calendar setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help, exactly the  problem  was in  this part the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think there is an error in your library calling lines please call them by using following sequence

```
{!!Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') !!}
{!! Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js')!!}
{!! Html::script('vendor/maryem/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') !!}
```